# Does the "Serpents of flame" standard sustain include the attack?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Serpents of flame power is a daily with a standard attack and an opportunity action (both daily)

The sustain for the effect (required for either action) is either a minor or a standard (the one I'm worried about).  The standard is worded like this:

"The effect persists until the end of your next turn and you can repeat this power's attacks."

What I'm wondering is, do you have to sustain it (standard) and then wait for the next turn to attack (standard), or can you attack with the same action you use to sustain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moment you use the Sustain feature of the power, you repeat the power's attacks (if you want to). Repeating the attacks is part of the sustain itself, and you do not wait until your next turn to do it. So it would work like this:

**Turn 1:** Use your power, applying an effect that lasts to the end of your next turn.
**Turn 2:** Sustain the power, and repeat the attacks. The effect is renewed to last until the end of your next turn.
**Turn 3:** Repeat what you did on step 2.

Comment: I think it's the fact that it's 2 attacks that threw me.  The second being an OA, you can't take it immediately (So they can't both "repeat" as part of the sustaining action) and this got me to thinking that in this case the Sustain was more of a recharge/reset that allowed you to use the daily power and daily OA again, but I think you are right.

Comment: @BillK If there are unusual specifics for this power it would be worth quoting the power itself, in as much detail as is provided (including all keywords, the various lines of the power in the order they're printed, etc). I'm under the impression doing so is OK under fair use, since it's for analysis. From the Compendium, this appears to be a power from one of the Magazines, so I won't be able to look it up myself. The Magazines are also a little notorious for introducing weird powers which don't use 4e's power writing conventions properly and thus have strange and unique rules situations.